# Amazon Redshift VACUUM error

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, redshift

I'm trying to run vacuum delete only on a table with big amount of columns (800+) and 4 million rows.

I know it's recommended to use deep copy instead, but still am wondering if running vacuum is still possible on such big table.
This is my error:

```
vacuum_max_buffer is too small to vacuum table <table> - need at least: 3388MB
```

is it possible to change the value of vacuum_max_buffer (set vacuum_max_buffer=xxxxx), or is it best not to change this and go on with the deep copy?

Thanks,
Meny

Comment: Thanks very much for accurately identifying your use of Redshift, not just saying "PostgreSQL". Of course, that means I have no idea how to help, as `vacuum_max_buffer` seems to be a RedShift/ParAccel specific parameter that isn't in mainline PostgreSQL.